# rotateY() text is blurry/pixelated

Tags: html, css, css-animations, perspective

I've rotated and perspective-3d an element with text.  The text is really low fidelity.  Is there any way to improve it?

Really simple example code:

```
<h1 style = "transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-45deg);width:150px;">
    This is text
</h1>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPxWQa?editors=100

Comment: Looks nice to me. Fuzzy on the last letter, but you'd expect that when scaling up significantly. Screenshot? What browser are you on?

Comment: @henry The effect is most visible on the last letter like you said.  If you're seeing that, you're seeing the effect I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need parent container for right perspective.

```
-webkit-perspective: 900px;
```

Hover the text for visulization

```css
div {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
}

h1:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 60% 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is text</h1>
<div>
```

Or see this example

```css
.container {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">This a div text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 10 degree rotation isn't an issue.  I'm doing 45 degree rotation.  I tried adding a perspective on the parent element, but then the rotations got all messed up - maybe I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: @Pickle see my second example

Comment: You code example appears to work here, but not when I try to duplicate it.  In any case, the pixellation (or rather, the blurriness & apparent lack of aliasing) still appears.  I'm now thinking that's just the state of things as it is.  I was hoping there was a way to force the browser to morph the grid on which it draws the text, but it appears all that can be done is morph the grid AFTER the text is drawn.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This looks better:

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Arial'; transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-45deg); width: 300px;">
This is text</h1>
```

Or this:

```
<h1 style = "text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-45deg);width:150px;">This is text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the text, the standard transform origin is center.

That mean that the right part of the text is getting nearer to the viewer, and so is zoomed in.

With a little bit of experimentation, you can get a similar effect setting the transform origin to the right - so that all text is going far away - and then increasing the font size.

That is, the right letter would be rendered in a bigger font, and not zoomed in, resulting in a less blurred font, but of the same size

```css
h1 {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-45deg);width:150px;
  background: yellow;
}


#test {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-30deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
  font-size: 4em;
  width:325px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is text</h1>
<h1 id="test">This is text</h1>
```